# dynamic sql error: 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, dynamic-sql

As part of some administrative tasks, we have many tables that each need a trigger created. The trigger will set a flag and the date in the Audit database when an object has been modified. For simplicity, I have a table with all the objects that need triggers created.

I am trying to generate some dynamic sql to do this for each object, but I am getting this error:
`'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.`

Here is the code to generate the sql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [spCreateTableTriggers]
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @dbname     varchar(50),
        @schemaname varchar(50),
        @objname    varchar(150),
        @objtype    varchar(150),
        @sql        nvarchar(max),
        @CRLF       varchar(2)

SET     @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

DECLARE ObjectCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  DatabaseName,SchemaName,ObjectName
FROM    Audit.dbo.ObjectUpdates;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

OPEN    ObjectCursor ;

FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor
INTO    @dbname,@schemaname,@objname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

    SET @sql = N'USE '+QUOTENAME(@dbname)+'; '
    SET @sql = @sql + N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+QUOTENAME(@schemaname)+'.[Tiud_'+@objname+'_AuditObjectUpdates]'')) '
    SET @sql = @sql + N'BEGIN DROP TRIGGER '+QUOTENAME(@schemaname)+'.[Tiud_'+@objname+'_AuditObjectUpdates]; END; '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'CREATE TRIGGER '+QUOTENAME(@schemaname)+'.[Tiud_'+@objname+'_AuditObjectUpdates] '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'   ON '+QUOTENAME(@schemaname)+'.['+@objname+'] '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AS '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Audit.dbo.ObjectUpdates WHERE DatabaseName = '''+@dbname+''' AND ObjectName = '''+@objname+''' AND RequiresUpdate=0'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'BEGIN'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    SET NOCOUNT ON;'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    UPDATE  Audit.dbo.ObjectUpdates'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    SET RequiresUpdate = 1'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    WHERE   DatabaseName = '''+@dbname+''' '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'        AND ObjectName = '''+@objname+''' '+@CRLF

    SET @sql = @sql + N'END' +@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'ELSE' +@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'BEGIN' +@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    SET NOCOUNT ON;' +@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + @CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    -- Update ''SourceLastUpdated'' date.'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    UPDATE  Audit.dbo.ObjectUpdates'+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    SET SourceLastUpdated = GETDATE() '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'    WHERE   DatabaseName = '''+@dbname+''' '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'        AND ObjectName = '''+@objname+''' '+@CRLF
    SET @sql = @sql + N'END; '+@CRLF

    --PRINT(@sql);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor
    INTO    @dbname,@schemaname,@objname;

END

CLOSE ObjectCursor ;
DEALLOCATE ObjectCursor ;

END
```

If I use `PRINT` and paste the code to a new query window, the code executes without any problem.

I have removed the `GO` statements as this was also giving errors.

What am I missing?
Why am I getting an error using `EXEC(@sql);` or even `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`?
Is this something to do with the context within `EXEC()`?
Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use SSMS (or other similar tool) to run the code produced by *this* script, you will get exactly the same error. It could run all right when you inserted batch delimiters (`GO`), but now that you don't, you'll face the same issue in SSMS too.

On the other hand, the reason why you cannot put `GO` in your dynamic scripts is because `GO` isn't a SQL statement, it's merely a delimiter recognised by SSMS and some other tools. Probably you are already aware of that.

Anyway, the point of `GO` is for the tool to know that the code should be split and its parts run *separately*. And that, *separately*, is what you should do in your code as well.

So, you have these options:

- insert `EXEC sp_execute @sql` just after the part that drops the trigger, then reset the value of `@sql` to then store and run the definition part in its turn;
- use two variables, `@sql1` and `@sql2`, store the IF EXISTS/DROP part into `@sql1`, the CREATE TRIGGER one into `@sql2`, then run both scripts (again, separately).

But then, as you've already found out, you'll face another issue: you cannot create a trigger in another database without running the statement *in the context of that database*.

Now, there are 2 ways of providing the necessary context:

1) use a `USE` statement;

2) run the statement(s) as a dynamic query using `EXEC targetdatabase..sp_executesql N'…'`.

Obviously, the first option isn't going to work here: we cannot add `USE …` before `CREATE TRIGGER`, because the latter must be the only statement in the batch.

The second option *can* be used, but it will require an additional layer of *dynamicity* (not sure if it's a word). It's because the database name is a parameter here and so we need to run `EXEC targetdatabase..sp_executesql N'…'` *as* a dynamic script, and since the actual script to run is itself supposed to be a dynamic script, it, therefore, will be nested twice.

So, before the (second) `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` line add the following:

```
SET @sql = N'EXEC ' + @dbname + '..sp_executesql N'''
           + REPLACE(@sql, '''', '''''') + '''';
```

As you can see, to integrate the contents of `@sql` as a nested dynamic script properly, they must be enclosed in single quotes. For the same reason, every single quotation mark *in* `@sql` must be doubled (e.g. using the [`REPLACE()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), as in the above statement).

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have now split the code into two 'pieces' as you suggest in your first option above, as follows:

Comment: [EDIT timed out on previous comment.]
Many thanks. I have split the code into two 'pieces' as you suggest in your first option. The first part executes perfectly.
I will clarify that the procedure is executed from the 'Audit' database and the objects which require triggers are in other databases.
Excecuting the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement now throws the following error, even when using fully qualified table name:
"Cannot create trigger on [...] as the target is not in the current database."
Is there any way around this? How can I get it to execute within the context of another database?
Thanks.

Comment: @markb: Please see my update. I'm not sure if everything is as clear as I would like it to be, so please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: This is excellent, perfectly clear and is exactly what I was after.
The only problem - I checked in BOL - was with `QUOTENAME`, where the string parameter is limited to 128 characters. Inputs greater than 128 characters return `NULL`, so I have put quotes around it instead of using the function.
I can now see how `'EXEC'+@dbname+'..sp_executesql'` can be extremely powerful and allow executing dynamic sql under another context/database.
Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: @markb: Ah, indeed, my bad. You could replace the functionality of `QUOTENAME` with something like `'''' + REPLACE(@sql, '''', '''''') + ''''`. (I.e. I think it is not enough just to enclose `@sql` in quotation marks, but because you have string expressions inside the trigger definition, you'll also need to double each quote there.)

Comment: +1 Ah, yes, I forgot about strings within the string! `REPLACE()` does the job perfectly. It all executes without a hitch! You've just made my weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a much better approach when using dynamic sql within dynamic sql - side effect: no need to replace quotes and a like:

```
DECLARE
    @originalsql NVARCHAR(4000) = N' ..... '
    , @stmt NVARCHAR(200) = 'otherdatabase.dbo.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql'
    , @params NVARCHAR(200) = '@sql NVARCHAR(4000)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt=@stmt, @params=@params, @sql = @originalsql
```

Answer (score 0):

a trigger creation must be done on its own execution batch. You are inside a procedure so you wont be able to create it.

I suggest adding the @sql into a temp table and then once the proc is finish generating all of the statements, loop this temp table to execute them and create the triggers